Display full feature information for multiple layers
I am compiling a map for a local Conservation Cluster of Farms which is hosted on QGIS Cloud. I have delineated each holding with an outline in one layer with contact information in an attribute table and a second layer with individual fields with their own details in their own attribute table. Everything in the fields layer exists within the area delineated by the outline. These layers are held as a group in the local working copy of QGIS. In the uploaded map, when you click on a field on the map the full information for either layer is only displayed in the features table if the other layer is hidden. I would ideally like it, if a field is clicked on, for the holding details from the outline layer to be displayed and the field information too from the fields layer. Is this possible?
These pictures should illustrate and the live map can be found here https://qgiscloud.com/HighStoy/High_Stoy
With just the Outline, this is the ideal Holding Information output

With just the field layer, here is its ideal output

With both layers visible, the information is no longer shown

Is it possible to get the full Feature Information output for both layers at once?
